# Luxon is failing to parse this date format

Tags: javascript, node.js, luxon

I'm trying to figure out why luxon is failing to parse this date format.

This is the original value I have: `2019-04-23T23:15:07.910Z`.

What format is this (it looks like an iso format).

Code snippet:

```js
console.log('document.lastUpdatedAt = ', document.lastUpdatedAt)

const fromISO = DateTime.fromISO(document.lastUpdatedAt)
console.log('fromISO = ', fromISO)

const fromSQL = DateTime.fromSQL(document.lastUpdatedAt)
console.log('fromSQL = ', fromSQL)

const fromHTTP = DateTime.fromHTTP(document.lastUpdatedAt)
console.log('fromHTTP = ', fromHTTP)
```

Output from snippet above:

```js
document.lastUpdatedAt =  2019-04-23T23:15:07.910Z
test =  test
fromISO =  DateTime {
  ts: 1556062543882,
  _zone: LocalZone {},
  loc:
   Locale {
     locale: 'en',
     numberingSystem: null,
     outputCalendar: null,
     intl: 'en',
     weekdaysCache: { format: {}, standalone: {} },
     monthsCache: { format: {}, standalone: {} },
     meridiemCache: null,
     eraCache: {},
     specifiedLocale: null,
     fastNumbersCached: null },
  invalid:
   Invalid {
     reason: 'unparsable',
     explanation:
      'the input "Tue Apr 23 2019 16:15:07 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)" can\'t be parsed as ISO 8601' },
  weekData: null,
  c: null,
  o: null,
  isLuxonDateTime: true }
fromSQL =  DateTime {
  ts: 1556062543889,
  _zone: LocalZone {},
  loc:
   Locale {
     locale: 'en',
     numberingSystem: null,
     outputCalendar: null,
     intl: 'en',
     weekdaysCache: { format: {}, standalone: {} },
     monthsCache: { format: {}, standalone: {} },
     meridiemCache: null,
     eraCache: {},
     specifiedLocale: null,
     fastNumbersCached: null },
  invalid:
   Invalid {
     reason: 'unparsable',
     explanation:
      'the input "Tue Apr 23 2019 16:15:07 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)" can\'t be parsed as SQL' },
  weekData: null,
  c: null,
  o: null,
  isLuxonDateTime: true }
fromHTTP =  DateTime {
  ts: 1556062543890,
  _zone: LocalZone {},
  loc:
   Locale {
     locale: 'en',
     numberingSystem: null,
     outputCalendar: null,
     intl: 'en',
     weekdaysCache: { format: {}, standalone: {} },
     monthsCache: { format: {}, standalone: {} },
     meridiemCache: null,
     eraCache: {},
     specifiedLocale: null,
     fastNumbersCached: null },
  invalid:
   Invalid {
     reason: 'unparsable',
     explanation: 'the input "[object Object]" can\'t be parsed as HTTP' },
  weekData: null,
  c: null,
  o: null,
  isLuxonDateTime: true }
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ahh just figured it out. Turns out `2019-04-23T23:15:07.910Z` is actually a javascript date object.

This means I needed to do `const fromJSDate = DateTime.fromJSDate(document.lastUpdatedAt)`

Comment: For me, it's `fromJSDate` - not sure if API changed or a typo.